# How to implement consistent domain objects in multiple programming languages?

Tags: javascript, java, python, software-design

I am trying to generate domain models for some shared library. I want those domain models to be used by clients using different languages (e.g. java, python, javascript, ruby etc).

For example, I want these generated based on the language I am using in a consistent manner.

In Java:

```
@Data // to indicate all basic getters/setters etc are there
class Point {
  private int x;
  private int y;
}
```

In Python:

```
class Point:
  def __init__():
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0

  // other getter/setter/properties
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

1. Maintain separate repositories of the models implemented in different languages with tighter version control? - Doable with least imagination, but looks tedious and error prone to me.
2. Some sort of framework that spits out models/classes in different languages provided some common definition in xml/yml/json/some dsl? This would be ideal choice for me. Unfortunately I am not aware of any such open source/paid public framework. Is there anything like this available? Is it achievable using [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org)?
3. Anything else?

Also, is this a bad design choice?

**Edit:** People who are suggesting this as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278675/programming-language-independent-model-validation), it's exactly opposite of the linked question. That one asks for validating models across different application in varying languages. My question is generating models based on common definition!

That question was asked 7 years ago! Technology has evolved a lot since then! The most upvoted answer suggests,

> "Your best bet would be a framework that allows you to specify model validation in a language agnostic format"

which is not any definitive answer either!

Why are people so eager to discard any question instead of promoting discussion in a Q&A site? This is clear abuse of power and essentially discourage people to contribute! A few days ago I saw a memo from the StackOverflow team about improving new user engagement and experience. Meh..

Comment: protocol buffers from google. corba idl. rest. soap. dcom.

Comment: Define one XSD to describe data in language agnostic way. Use code generators to create DTOs in each language from the XSD.